# Javascript go to inner key by an index

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript object like this:

```
 var json = {
    a : "xxxx",
    b : {
        p : 12,
        a : "xxxx",
        b : {
            r : 1,
            a : "xxxx",
            b : null
        }
    }
}
```

and i want a function that passing in as parameters a key, an index and an object, add this last object to the object at the inner level indicated by the index.
I know, I have not explained well, an example:

```
function addObjectToJSON(key,index,object){
    var helpJSON = json;
    for(var i = 0; i < index; i++){
        helpJSON = helpJSON[key];
    }
    helpJSON = object;     

}
```

the above function obviously does not work.

i want that the result of this:

```
addObjectToJSON("b",2,{ a: 2, b: null});
```

was:

```
var json = {
    a : "xxxx",
    b : {
        p : 12,
        a : "xxxx",
        b : {
            r : 1,
            a : "xxxx",
            b : {
                 a : 2,
                 b : null   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that looks like an object, not json.

Comment: I’m not sure index is the right word. Do you mean nesting level? I don’t see the connection to indexes. What does the argument `2` do? Can you provide examples for other numbers?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what your question is, and I've spent some time trying to figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var json = {
a : "xxxx",
b : {
    p : 12,
    a : "xxxx",
    b : {
        r : 1,
        a : "xxxx",
        b : null
    }
}
```

}

//addObjectToJSON

```
function addObjectToJSON(key,index,object,indexes = ""){

      if(index < 0){
          return false;
      }


    var jsonHelp = json;

    if(indexes != ""){
        var indexesSplit = indexes.split(".");

        for(var i = 0; i < indexesSplit.length; i++){        
            jsonHelp = jsonHelp[indexesSplit[i]];            
        }
    }else{
      if(index == 0){
          json[key] = object;
          console.log(json);
          return false;
      }
    }


    for(keyHelp in jsonHelp){
        if(key == keyHelp){
            index--;
            if(indexes == ""){
                indexes = key;
            }else{
                indexes += "."+key;
            } 
            if(index > -1){
                addObjectToJSON(key,index,object,indexes);
                break;
            }
        }        
   };   

   if(index <= -1){
       jsonHelp[key] = object;      
       var indixesHelp = ""
       for(var i = 0; i < indexesSplit.length; i++){        
           indixesHelp += "."+indexesSplit[i];         
       }
       eval("json"+indixesHelp+" = jsonHelp");        

       console.log(json);
   }


}
```